# Is it possible to export a Video with transparent Background? (No Image Sequences!)

Tags: after-effects, quicktime, adobe-media-encoder, alpha

Is it possible to export a video file from After Effects with transparency?

I don't want to export to an image sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File > Add to Render Queue > Output mode > Format 'Quicktime' / Channels 'RGB + Alpha'

See if that works for you!

Comment: Yep that works.. as mentioned in my comment in @Mulvya 's answer. But its sad its not possible to set up in Adobe Media Encoder

Comment: Ah yes, Media Encoder - do you have the GoPro Cineform Codec? I believe if comes with latest versions on Media Encoder. If so...you can choose Quicktime > GoPro Cineform with Alpha.

Answer (score 7):

#### Production codecs with alpha channel support

- Apple ProRes 4444 / Apple ProRes 4444 XQ

  From the [Manual](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202410):

  > Apple ProRes 4444 and Apple ProRes 4444 XQ are ideal for the exchange of motion graphics media because they are virtually lossless. They are also the only Apple ProRes codecs that support alpha channels.
- DNxHD

  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNxHD_codec):

  > lossy high-definition video post-production codec engineered for multi-generation compositing with reduced storage and bandwidth requirements
  >
  > The codec supports alpha channel information.
- DNxHR

  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNxHR_codec):

  > lossy UHDTV post-production codec engineered for multi-generation compositing with reduced storage and bandwidth requirements
- CineForm

  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CineForm)

  > Current implementations support image formatting for 10-bit 4:2:2 YUV, 12-bit 4:4:4 RGB and RGBA, and 12-bit CFA Bayer filter RAW compression

---

#### Uncompressed with alpha

- Quicktime Animation Codec
- AVI uncompressed (None)

From the After Effects [Manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/alpha-channels-masks-mattes.html):

> When specifying the color depth for an output image, the plus sign (as in Millions Of Colors+) denotes an alpha channel. Similarly, choosing to output to 32 bits per pixel implies an output depth of 8 bits per channel for each of four channels: RGBA.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for the Quicktime output module, choose to output `RGB + Alpha` using PNG or Animation codec.

In Media Encoder, choose Depth as `32 Bit` after selecting the same codecs as above.

Comment: there is no option in the mdeia encoders output module for an rgb or rgbA channel...

Comment: I saw it in the render que in after effects but not in the media encoders one